# How do I setup Kryo as a substitute for Writable as a serialization framework in HDFS/Hadoop

Tags: serialization, hadoop, hdfs, kryo

How do I setup Kryo as my serialization framework in place of Writable?

Sub Question: How do I set up my objects to be serialized/deserialized as we do for [Writable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Set the io.serializations property to a comma-separated list of classnames to register Serialization implementations. Its default value is org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization, which means that only Writable objects can be serialized or deserialized out of the box.

Refer - http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id4397802